# vs2010 C4353 why isn't this an error

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

I ran into this today in an if and after looking into it found that all these are all valid statements that generate the C4353  .  My only guess is that this is the old way of doing noop in C.  Why is this not an error.  When would you use this to do anything useful.

```
int main()
{
    nullptr();
    0();
    (1 == 2)();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: GCC-4.3.4 issues [errors for all three](http://www.ideone.com/sy9cd),which pretty much tells us these are supported by VC2010 as compiler extensions.

Comment: What do you mean as "all these are all valid statements"? I know at least one more compiler, other than Visual C++ 10.0 that fails to compile this code. p.s. vs2010 is not a name of compiler, you are saying something along "I compile this code from Vim" ... :-)

Comment: The tricky part is if you have an if something like a == nullptr (x =y) which is what I had.  Someone forgot an && and it doesn't do at all what you think.

Comment: @mloskot thank you for pedantic error. The correct version is Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for x64

Comment: @rerun Nice. Try to compile with /Za switch and compare the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using constant 0 as a function expression is an extension that is specific to Microsoft. They implemented this specifically because they saw a reason for it, which explains why it's wouldn't make sense to treat it as an error. But since it's non-standard, the compiler emits a warning.

You are correct that it is an alternative to using __noop().

Answer (score 1):

All of these :

```
    nullptr();
    0();
    (1 == 2)();
```

are no-op statements (meaning they don't do anything).

btw I hope you are not ignoring warnings. Most of the time it is a good practice to fix all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [C4353 warning page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a68558f.aspx) and in the [`__noop` intrinsic documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6btaxcs.aspx), the use of `0` as a function expression instructs the Microsoft C++ compiler to ignore calls to the function but still generate code that evaluates its arguments (for side effects).

The example given is a trace macro that gets `#defined` either to `__noop` or to a print function, depending on the value of the `DEBUG` preprocessor symbol:

```
#if DEBUG
   #define PRINT   printf_s
#else
   #define PRINT   __noop
#endif

int main() {
   PRINT("\nhello\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a68558f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for that warning has ample explanation and a motivating example:

```
// C4353.cpp
// compile with: /W1
void MyPrintf(void){};
#define X 0
#if X
   #define DBPRINT MyPrint
#else
   #define DBPRINT 0   // C4353 expected
#endif
int main(){
    DBPRINT();
}
```

As you can see it is to support archaic macro usage.